# Use of std::allocator_traits<A>

Tags: c++, allocator

I would like to design a class template which takes an allocator type (as defined in Standard section 17.6.3.5) as a template argument.  I see how `std::allocator_traits<A>` helpfully fills in any missing members of `A` with default settings.  Beyond that, is there anything in the Standard Library or boost that would help use the allocator correctly?

In particular:

1. To honor the typedefs like `std::allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment`, do I have to check these things in the special member functions of each class which has a member of type `A`?  Or is there some wrapper type I could use as a member instead which would take care of this stuff?
2. If I want to overallocate to reduce the number of allocations by storing extra data next to the user-visible objects, is it appropriate to rebind the allocator something like this?

.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
class MyClass
{
private:
    //...
    struct storage {
        int m_special_data;
        T m_obj;
    };
    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<A>::template rebind_alloc<storage>
        storage_alloc;
    typedef typename std::allocator_traits<A>::template rebind_traits<storage>
        storage_traits;
    storage_alloc m_alloc;

    static T* alloc(T&& obj)
    {
        storage_traits::pointer sp = storage_traits::allocate(m_alloc, 1);
        sp->m_special_data = 69105;
        return ::new(&sp->m_obj) T(std::move(obj));
    }
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know of anything to make life easier, `allocator_traits` *really* makes it simpler to write an allocator, by providing all the boilerplate code, but it doesn't help *use* an allocator.

So that I could use a single allocator API in both C++03 and C++11 code I added `<ext/alloc_traits.h>` to GCC 4.7, the class template `__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits` provides a consistent API that uses `allocator_traits` in C++11 mode and calls the relevant member functions directly on the allocator in C++03 mode.

1. No, there's no wrapper or shortcut, the C++11 allocator requirements make a container author's job *much* more complicated.  The requirements are slightly different for each container, depending on how it manages memory.  For a vector-like type, in the copy-assignment operator if `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` (POCCA) is false and the existing capacity is greater than the source object's size then you can re-use the existing memory (if POCCA is true and the new allocator is not equal you can't re-use the old memory as it won't be possible to de-allocate  it later after the allocator is replaced) but that optimization doesn't help much for a node-based container such as list or map.
2. That looks almost right, although you probably want to replace

   ```
   return ::new(&sp->m_obj) T(std::move(obj));
   ```

   with

   ```
   A a(m_alloc);    
   std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(a, &sp->m_obj, std::move(obj));
   return &sp->m_obj;
   ```

As stated in [container.requirements.general]/3 the containers which use an allocator use `allocator_traits<A>::construct` to create the element type `T` itself but any other types allocated (such as your `storage`) must not use `construct`.

If `storage` itself is constructed then it will construct `storage::m_obj` unless that member is a type which can be left uninitialized, such as `std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T)>`, that can be initialized explicitly later by `allocator_traits<A>::construct`. Alternatively, individually construct each member that needs non-trivial construction e.g. if `storage` also had a `string` member:

```
    storage_traits::pointer sp = storage_traits::allocate(m_alloc, 1);
    sp->m_special_data = 69105;
    ::new (&sp->m_str) std::string("foobar");
    A a(m_alloc);    
    std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(a, &sp->m_obj, std::move(obj));
    return &sp->m_obj;
```

The `m_special_data` member is a trivial type so its lifetime begins as soon as storage is allocated for it. The `m_str` and `m_obj` members need non-trivial initialization so their lifetimes begin when their constructors complete, which is done by the placement new and the `construct` call, respectively.

**Edit**: I've recently learnt that the standard has a defect (which I've reported) and the calls to `construct` do not need to use a rebound allocator, so these lines:

```
    A a(m_alloc);    
    std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(a, &sp->m_obj, std::move(obj));
```

can be replaced with:

```
    std::allocator_traits<storage_alloc>::construct(m_alloc, &sp->m_obj, std::move(obj));
```

Which makes life slightly easier.

Comment: Doesn't "any other types allocated must not use `construct`" contradict the suggestion `storage_traits::construct(m_alloc, &sp);`, or does that not count because of the `rebind`?  If I do construct `storage` and it still has a member of type `T`, then that member gets constructed along with the `storage`, and not by `construct`.  So I would need to do some sort of `union` or `static_cast` from `void` trick?

Comment: As for your second question, yes, you could use a union, or a suitably-sized and suitably-aligned array of `char`.  In my experience it's easier to just ensure `storage` only contains trivially-constructible data apart from the `T`, so you can `construct` the `T` and simply assign values to the other parts (usually just pointers and/or integers). I'll edit my answer to reflect that.